# How clone and init Datepicker via vanilla JS correctly in Tailwind Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I use [Tailwind Elements library](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/datepicker/) with Tailwind CSS in my project.
Everything works perfectly, but there is one problem appeared... because I'm trying to clone the element and add to the page a copy.

I do the clone of a form with [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method like this:

1. I have hidden HTML template:

```
<template id="temp">
  <form>
    <div class="datepicker relative mb-3" data-mdb-toggle-button="false">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Select a date" data-mdb-toggle="datepicker" />
      <label class="text-gray-700">Select a date</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

2. When user clicks a button somewhere in the page "+ Add new form", then the new form will be added to the page. There can be many forms as user wants. So I want to use this template to clone it and insert new and new and new nodes to the page. JS:

```
import 'tw-elements'
let newForm = document.querySelector("#temp").content.cloneNode(true); // clone the <form>
     newForm.appendChild(document.body); // add to the <body>
```

After these manipulations the new form added to the page, **but the Datepicker does not work**.
As I understood, I should call the initialization of the element programmably via JS like this:

```
let datePicker = newForm.querySelect('.datepicker');
datePicker.tweDatePicker(); // smth like that maybe
```

Right? But how? I cannot find in the docs how to call and init the Datepicker (or any other component) via vanilla JS programmably?
Maybe you know the better approaches.

Comment: I tried it and yes, there is a problem and I think it's on library lvl.
I tried many variants to add form like you - none of them works, exept if I put in worked html, so maybe(maybe!) right now library is parsing html at start nad init all used elements, the dynamic adds - not.

I tried also daisyUI for comparing and it works fine in dynamic components adding. 
I found other problems like nextjs(also dynamic render) problems.

Switch to another library till it comes fixed

Comment: @Mero I think this is a bad idea to refuse Tailwind Elements. I don't want to refactor all the app and switch to another UI library only because of that reason. dude. I believe there should be the way to use it programally and reinit the components on the page.

Comment: Hope you are right, but it's alpha, you should think about it when choose it.